# Which is the best way to hide the PHP source code?

Tags: php, encryption

Which is the best way to convert the PHP code to not human readble format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP- Best Obfuscation Tool/Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777229/php-best-obfuscation-tool-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/).

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a duplicate of [PHP- Best Obfuscation Tool/Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777229/php-best-obfuscation-tool-script) however nobody there mentioned [hiphop](http://wiki.github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/).

Comment: hiphop is a PHP compiler; it's main purpose is to speed up the code. The fact that it becomes unreadable as a compiled executable is a bonus.

Comment: No one mentioned hiphop for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the [Ioncube Encryption](http://www.ioncube.com/), but you will need to ask your server administrator to install the Ioncube library / package, if it's not already installed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Be warned that ioncube is pretty heavy on your customer's IT folks nerves.

Answer (score 0):

You can see bcompiler with a stable release:
http://pecl.php.net/package/bcompiler