# How to hide source code of a php script?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Code obfuscator for php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php)
>   [Which is the best way to hide the PHP source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777500/which-is-the-best-way-to-hide-the-php-source-code)

Hello, 
I searched for answer in previous titles but i couldn't find correct one excatly.
I preperad a php script for my customer but i want to hide source code.Maybe he can use it to sell to anybody.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064973/minify-obfuscate-php-code

Comment: you best options are legal ones, not obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many other questions on this site discussing this. You're referring to a [PHP Obfuscator](http://www.bing.com/search?q=php+obfuscator&form=APMCS1). Search around; you'll find a lot of ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obfuscate your code you could look into Zend Guard. But I doubt you need to go that far - make sure you communicate in your terms of business that the code is not for resale.